# How to use proxy script in jvm parameters

Tags: proxy, jvm-arguments, proxy-server

I beleive experts might have came across several proxy server configuration at jvm level.
I also have same, where in i am stuck at a point where i want to specifically specify browser script as jvm parameters, but not able to do so.

Could you please help?

I tried to setup script using java configuration setting from control panel.
I used proxy host and port, but that is asking for authentication(do not want to goto that path.)